# AWS Config and Troposhpere

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, troposphere, aws-config

I'm looking for documentation on how to configure [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) utilizing Troposphere. Unfortunately I am having a hard time finding useful documentation for this particular case. I've looked over the Troposphere documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) but can't seem to find anything relevant. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know AWS Config myself, so can't help a ton there, but here is the Cloudformation documentation for all the available AWS Config resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-reference-config.html

and here are the corresponding troposphere objects:

https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/config.py

One thing to note is that troposphere tries to be a 1:1 translation of the CF Template spec, so you can usually work off of existing Cloudformation documentation/examples, but convert them to the troposphere/python syntax.  An example:

In Cloudformation, to make a bucket you would use this:

```
MyBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: my-bucket
```

Which converts into troposphere as such:

```
from troposphere import s3, Template

t = Template()
my_s3_bucket = t.add_resource(
    s3.Bucket(
        "MyBucket",
        BucketName="my-bucket",
    )
)
```

Hope that helps, sorry I don't know more about AWS Config!